# AIR - Different behaviour when the app is installed and when it runs inside the builder

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder

we are developing an Adobe AIR app using Flex4. We are facing lot of bugs that didn't show up when we run the application inside Flash Builder (both debug mode and run mode), but when we install the app and run it, the app shows a different behaviour. Any idea ? what does it change between running the installed application in the builder and outside ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There's a handfull of different things, ApplicationIds, fiel directory paths, etc... What sort of bugs are you seeing, and maybe we could narrow it down?

Comment: Do you mean that you are running the app in Flash Builder (AKA Design Mode?)  Or are you launching it from Flash Builder?  I assume you mean the second.  I'd check to make sure that your dev SDK runtime matches your deployment runtime; as things often change between versions of the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've founded the problem using MonsterDebugger in the application running stand alone. The problem was the File.browseForDirectory(). I'm creating the File object, registering the event listener and then calling File.browseForDirectory() and that generate an exception. I switched the order, First creating a new file, then calling File.browseForDirectory() and at last register an event handler and works great.

My guess is that inside the debugger version and inside Flash Builder it takes just few more millisec and the File object is ready when i register the eventlistener but in the stand alone application AS3 code for event listener registration is executed before the File object initialization.